# Regular expression string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, special-characters

I want to explain my problem about a command string submitted from the client to the server. Through this specific command I have to login into the database managed by the server. According to the project's guide lines, command's formatting is: login@username;password. The string is sent to the server through a socket. User inserts his credentials and these are sent to the server putting them into the command. The server has to split the user and the password from the command and has to check, in the database, if the user already exists. Here is my problem, given the fact that in the user and in the password can be present ; (the same character of the separator), I don't understand (server side) how can i divide user and psw from the command so that user and psw are the same of the ones inserted in the client.

Have you got some ideas about? I was thinking to use regular expression, is this the right way?

Comment: If the username and password can also contain one or more semi-colons, then this is not possible. How should the server know which semi-colon is the separator, and which are part of the username and / or password? A regular expression is not going to solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would just split the string into a user/pass string like this:

```
String userPass = "User;Pass";
String[] parts = userPass.split(";");
String user = parts[0];
String pass = parts[1];
```

Comment: What if the username and / or the password contains one or more semi-colons, as Antonio mentioned in his question?

Comment: That's true, I didn't see he mentioned that.
edit: What would be best practice for something like this then? Split user/pass with something ridiculously abnormal? (e.g, ";3~a45n")

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to split a string by a separator included in both substrings there is no way to make sure the string is always split correctly!

I think you can use the unicode [unit separator character 0x001F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) to separate you strings safely, as the user will have some difficulties entering such a character!
But depending on your application and string processing this could cause damage, too, as there are some issues concerning incompatibilities (e.g. [xml 1.0 doesn't support it at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators)).

Otherwise if only one or none of the substrings may contain such a character you can easily use one of the already presented methods to split up the string and safely extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if User/password doesn't contain `@` or `;`

```
    String loginStr = "login@User;Password";

    String []splittedLogin = loginStr.split("@");

    String []loginCredentials = splittedLogin[1].split(";");

    String user = loginCredentials[0];
    String password = loginCredentials[1];

    System.out.println(user);
```